# Error in installing updates

Tags: installation

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.9_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still get the same error then:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Navigate to folder /var/cache/apt/archives and locate the file 'linux-firmware_1.79.9_all.deb'. Delete it.
Then repeat the above commands.

SOURCE: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191981